# Were titanium road bikes ridden in the Tour de France?

Tags: road-bike, frames, tour-de-france

I know that steel and aluminium frames were ridden in the Tour.
I wonder if there was a time when titanium frames were ridden in the Tour de France.
was ridden. I haven't found anything about this on the internet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this page](https://felixwong.com/2010/11/tour-de-france-bicycles-historical-bike-weights/), Luis Ocana won the tour on a Ti bike; Lance Armstrong (attach all necessary asterisks to his name) rode a Ti time-trial bike in 1999. It looks like Lotto raced on Litespeed Ti bikes in the early 00s (the Litespeed brand still exists, but the company that built those bikes is now doing business under the Lynskey name), for a while painted to look like a sponsor brand's bike, later with Litespeed decals. There are probably other instances--these are just the ones I was able to find quickly.

There are many instances of one bike brand sponsoring a team, while the bikes are actually built by someone else—for a while, the [BSO](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/887#887) brand Huffy sponsored a bike team, and the bikes were duly painted in Huffy livery, but the bikes were actually built by Serotta.

Comment: Thank you very much for the examples.

Comment: Fun fact: I believe that LA's '99 TT bike was a rebadged Litespeed Blade. If you Google, the Blade's top tube is aero shaped and it's also oriented vertically, meaning that it would reduce drag if the bike fell straight off a cliff, but it probably wouldn't help otherwise. This ESPN article shows a photo of LA in the '99 TT: https://www.espn.com/olympics/cycling/columns/story?columnist=ford_bonnie_d&id=4303217

Comment: The note about Lance Armstrong is unrelated, and adds nothing of value to the answer.

Comment: "duly painted in Huffy livery, but the bikes were actually built by Serotta" Ouch!

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  In 1991 the ["Z" Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A9dit_Agricole_(cycling_team)) lead by Greg LeMond, rode Merlin Ti bikes.

> In 1991, a year after winning his third Tour de France, Greg LeMond’s Z Team came back to the race on prototypes of the Merlin Extra Light. The first titanium bike to fully achieve the metal’s promise, it was as strong as steel but lighter, and possessed a unique and pleasing road feel—slightly more forgiving, with a little extra spring and, somewhat counterintuitively, also more stiffness. Though ­LeMond failed to win a fourth title, his bike sparked a fervor for titanium that lasted through the mid ’90s.
>
> <sub>Source: ["Nothing Like It: Titanium Dream Bikes," *Bicycling* magazine, November 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221150329/http://www.bicycling.com/bikes-gear/bikes-and-gear-features/nothing-it-titanium-dream-bikes) (web archive link)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The question has already been answered, but this is why I think titanium never really made it into the Tour. Ti frames are either a bit lighter or similar weight to steel bikes. They were also tricky to weld. Aluminum frames were clearly lighter than ti and the material was easier to weld. It was available contemporaneously with titanium. Furthermore, carbon was just starting to make inroads when ti had made it to the peloton.

Compounding this, I don't believe that any of the largest bike manufacturers aside from Colnago (the CT-1) had ti bikes. Remember that pro road racing relies on sponsorships, and larger bike brands are more able to offer sponship than smaller ones. Furthermore, the C40 carbon road bike was contemporaneous with the CT-1, and I think the C40 probably had more take up. I'm not sure if the CT-1 ever made it to pro road races. It may have, it's just not prominent enough for me to remember. Litespeed did sponsor a team as pointed out, but I'd characterize them as more a mid-sized manufacturer at the time.

Hence, titanium never had a window where it was the dominant material for performance bikes. Even if titanium working techniques were discovered and widely disseminated earlier, it would still have had to compete with aluminum. Even if a major brand had backed the material, I think they wouldn't have made wide market penetration given the available alternatives. And as stated above, I wonder if there was a good reason that almost all major brands didn't work with ti.

My recollection is that in the early 2000s, aluminum was probably the most common material. The US Postal Service team was sponsored by Trek, and they rode carbon Treks. I believe most Colnago teams went with the C40. I recall that around 2006 or 2007, the industry in general switched to carbon manufactured in Taiwan (whereas at the time Treks were made in the US, I think C40s were made in Italy, although their tubes were probably sourced overseas).

---

### Fun historical trivia

In 1999, Trek had not yet made a time trial bike. I believe the USPS team used rebadged Litespeed Blades that year. The Blade has a distinctive aero top tube, only the tube is oriented vertically. This would probably have made the bike stiffer vertically, which isn't desirable, and I suspect it would have done nothing for drag unless the bike were falling straight down.

This [ESPN link](https://www.espn.com/olympics/cycling/columns/story?columnist=ford_bonnie_d&id=4303217) has a picture of Lance Armstrong, who last won the [1998 Tour de Luxembourg](https://escapecollective.com/1998-tour-of-luxembourg-winner-to-pretend-to-go-to-mars/), at the time trial in the '99 Tour. Bicycle Blue Book has [a photo of the 2003](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/2003%20Litespeed%20Blade%20Ultegra/?condition=GOOD) (but not the '99) Blade. The Blade has a distinctive seat tube, with a mast-like extension above the top tube but taking a regular seat post. This [BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/sport/tour_de_france/385244.stm) shows a glimpse of the seat tube.

Another fun fact: I believe that Colnago outsourced the CT-1's production to [Wittson Cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittson_Custom_Ti_Cycles) (link to Wikipedia), a Lithuanian firm. I assume this had to be after the fall of the Soviet Union, whereas I think the C40 may have debuted earlier than that. [This page](https://steel-vintage.com/products/colnago-ct1-camoagnolo-record-10s-titanium-220524-02-13) on the blog Steel Vintage Bikes corroborates the Wikipedia statement about Wittson. If interested for historical reasons, [this thread on the Paceline forum](https://forums.thepaceline.net/showthread.php?t=220678) has a brief Q&A with the principal, Vidmantas Zukauskas.

Comment: If you want to make the material property argument, you should say a bit more than just "aluminium is lighter". Styrofoam is also lighter than titanium...

Comment: @leftaroundabout, why are there no helium bikes? :)

Comment: @paulgarrett hm, good question! I mean, it can't have anything to do with the fact that you'd need to keep your bike at -270°C lest it evaporate, right‽

Comment: @leftaroundabout, and, jeez, they're waaaay less flammable than the pure-hydrogen bikes. :)

Answer (score 3):

Gewiss Playbus, Bianchi Ti Mega Tube

---

Gewiss - Playbus was a team that rode in the 1996 TdF.   17 of the riders were Italian.

1. BERTOLETTI Simone
2. BERZIN Evgeni   (Russia)
3. BOBRIK Vladislav    (Russia)
4. BOTTARO Dario
5. BRIGNOLI Ermanno
6. BROGNARA Andrea
7. CENGHIALTA Bruno
8. CERIOLI Ivan
9. COLOMBO Gabriele
10. FINA Rosario
11. FRATTINI Francesco
12. GOTTI Ivan
13. MINALI Nicola
14. ODRIOZOLA Jon   (Spanish)
15. PERONA Davide
16. REZZANI Michele (trainee as from 01/09)
17. SANTAROMITA Mauro-Antonio
18. TARTAGGIA Giuseppe
19. VOLPI Alberto
20. ZANINI Stefano

<sub>Source https://www.procyclingstats.com/team/gewiss-playbus-1996/overview</sub>

---

They were sponsored by Biachi so rode their bicycles - this is Evgeni Berzin holding his Bianchi:

[image]

> Team Gewiss was sponsored by Bianchi back in 1995-96 seasons. Team Gewiss Playbus was winning with Bianchi’s top-end model, the ”Ti-Mega” which is made of lightweight 3AL-2.5V titanium tubeset.

> Team Gewiss Playbus  was one of the best team back in 1996. Their riders won biggest races like Milano-San Remo (G.Colombo), Amstel Gold Race (S.Zannini), Paris-Tours (N.Minali), stages at the Giro and Tour (E.Berzin) on Bianchi Ti-Mega bikes.

<sub>Source: https://premium-cycling.com/product/bianchi-ti-mega-titanium-team-gewiss-1996/</sub>

---

**ANSWER** Yes, this team rode Titanium bikes in the TdF in 1996, and Berzin won stage-8.

<sub>Source: https://www.procyclingstats.com/race/tour-de-france/1996/stage-8</sub>

Comment: Can you please add some context; rider(s), team, years, pictures, supporting sources?

Comment: Welcome to the site - I've expanded your answer, with sources and details.  Browsing https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer should help show you the level of detail needed in a useful answer, without going too long.

Answer (score 0):

Come on guys. Speedwell. Ocana. 1973. Victory.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Please note that the accepted answer already lists Ocana's victory among the times that a titanium bikes was used.  Please make sure you're adding new material when posting a new answer.